# JavaEE 7 webapp always shows recent address in address bar

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

When I start my webapp it shows correctly

```
https://myapp-anyone.rhcloud.com/index.jsf
```

Switching to login page or signup page does not change anything in the address bar, but then it always shows the recent address, never the current one. For example: From start I go to signup. Address bar: Same as above.
Then from signup page I switch to login page. Address bar:

```
https://myapp-anyone.rhcloud.com/pages/signup.jsf
```

Then from login page I switch back to start page. Address bar:

```
https://myapp-anyone.rhcloud.com/pages/login.jsf
```

and so on. The links are like

```
<h:commandLink action="pages/login" ... />
```

What could be the reason for that, and how to show the "correct" address?

Comment: Thank you for the hint of the possible duplicate. I will try the suggested solution from there. Question: What to do, when it IS a duplicate? Do I have to delete my post then?

Comment: @martin the help center has all the answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates . In short: no, you don't need to delete it. But you are free to do so.

Comment: In fact the answer of the other question helped.